# Scraping Yelp, but 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: python

I would like to scrape the restaurant and its popular dishes on Yelp.

At the begining, I was scraping Yelp with scrapy smoothly. But after a while, it pops up the error message of 503 Service Unavailable. And I also failed to access the Yelp website.

In the scrapy code, I've set my own user agent and set the robot.txt as False. Now I try to use the fake-agent package, but also failed.

Now I've sent an email to the Yelp team for the permission to enter the page. But I'm also concerning that if I scrape lots of info later, what if I'm blocked by Yelp again? It looks like rotating the user agents not work.

code in setting.py

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
BOT_NAME = "yelp"

SPIDER_MODULES = ["yelp.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "yelp.spiders"


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
#USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
USER_AGENT = ua.random
# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

code in the spider:

```
def parse(self, response):

        pagination_text = response.css('.css-1aq64zd .css-chan6m::text').get()
        if pagination_text:
            total_pages = int(pagination_text.split(' of ')[-1])

            for page_number in range(total_pages):
                start_value = page_number * 10
                #next_page_url = f"https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=New+York%2C+NY&start={start_value}"
                #next_page_url = f"https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA&start={start_value}"
                next_page_url = response.url + "&start={}".format(start_value)
                yield response.follow(next_page_url, callback=self.parse_page, headers={"User-Agent":ua.random})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to guess some, since I can't see all your code, but I think one of two things happened.

On the one hand, it's possible maybe you just couldn't connect to the their servers because of everyday network connectivity problems. This is legitimately possible because based on your target endpoint, the Yelp API isn't hosted on a separate domain (you'll sometimes see `api.something.com` or something). Granted, none of the status sites I checked just now show any problems, so if you know you didn't lose connectivity to other sites either this option is probably not too likely.

Unfortunately, the other option is more serious. There are a couple of things about the code you shared that concern me. For one thing, your comments (rightly) make a point to emphasize the importance of crawling responsibly, but it seems like you commented those lines out to try doing shady things.

There are legitimate reasons to repeat the same request to a website using different user agents (apparently web developers would send different responses to users based on the host agent in the early days of the internet), but disobeying the `robots.txt` file is both well-established bad internet etiquette and a huge red flag.

Looking at your snippet, I'm not seeing any checks to make sure you're not overwhelming the API with too many requests. This is a problem.

Whenever you access a server remotely (**especially** programmatically), you want to make sure you are doing everything you can to make it clear to any sysadmin you mean no harm. This means respecting the `robots.txt` file and any other resources, and heeding any requests from the server to throttle or pause your requests.

You should be checking the HTTP response headers; sysadmins will put anything they want you to know here, particularly if they want you to slow down your crawl. Not doing this means you could be inadvertently ignoring requests to throttle your traffic.

For example, here is a basic request to the GitHub API. I am checking the status code on the response here as usual, but I do nothing else.

```
>>> import requests
>>> result = requests.get('https://api.github.com/events')
>>> result.status_code
200
```

Here's the problem; if you look at the response headers, you'll immediately see some critical information.

```
>>> for header, content in result.headers.items(): print(header, content)
...
Server GitHub.com
Date Thu, 08 Feb 2024 07:59:33 GMT
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
Vary Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
ETag W/"af2e182835deb7bf575bbb3bc96dc17a5674d39890e4ca1a9c5c33f0efd7e259"
Last-Modified Thu, 08 Feb 2024 07:54:33 GMT
X-Poll-Interval 60
X-GitHub-Media-Type github.v3; format=json
Link <https://api.github.com/events?page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/events?page=10>; rel="last"
x-github-api-version-selected 2022-11-28
Access-Control-Expose-Headers ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options deny
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-XSS-Protection 0
Referrer-Policy origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy default-src 'none'
Content-Encoding gzip
X-RateLimit-Limit 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining 55
X-RateLimit-Reset 1707381389
X-RateLimit-Resource core
X-RateLimit-Used 5
Accept-Ranges bytes
Transfer-Encoding chunked
X-GitHub-Request-Id EE9D:3EB8:122B6E4:24F9BEE:65C489E5
```

Now consider what happens when you aren't rate-limiting your scraping requests. From the server's perspective, you look like either a denial of service attack or a selfish jerk (depending on how much your behavior is degrading the server's performance), and sysadmins only respond to these incidents one way: a ban.

These "bans" usually start out as requests returning errors with a [429 HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) "Too Many Requests" status code, but if you keep sending requests anyway, you get the honor and the privilege of a spot on their [`nftables`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nftables) configuration. There are tools like `fail2ban` that partially automate this process, too.

At the end of the day, [servers are constantly being attacked](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40291/strange-requests-to-web-server/40294#40294), and sysadmins will not hesitate to ban you.

This doesn't have to be a problem. If you want to crawl a site, look for documentation on whether that's allowed and how to properly do it; you'd be surprised how reasonable people can be (for instance, [here](https://info.arxiv.org/help/api/tou.html) is the Arxiv's terms of use for bulk access to their APIs). If you can't find any documentation, email the site admins.

Websites usually have either a `postmaster@url.com` or a `webmaster@url.com` email for things just like this. If you don't get a response, I would also try `abuse@url.com`. You'd be amazed how friendly people can be when you solve problems *before* they happen.

---

Circling back to your original question, I can't really say why you can't connect to the API, although based on some of the things in your code sample, I think you're definitely right to be fearing a ban; I wouldn't be shocked if that was the case.

If that's the case though, it's not the end of the world; there are billions of other sites. Just don't do it again, it's never too late to learn!

Comment: That's a very generous explanation!